# https webpage not opening unless its trusted in ie8

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver, trust

i have developed a java desktop application(jar) with the help of selenium webdriver.what it basically does is it opens a webpage(https) in a webbrowser in this case ie8 and does some form posting. But its unable to open the webpage(https) in ie unless i add the site in trust site zone of ie. I tried it on other browsers firefox and chome there is no problem,no tursting issues, the webpage is opened directly with ease.Why is it so in internetexplorer ? Why i have to trust the site in ie?

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your server configuration? do you access directly application server? do you have any load balancer or web server ?

Comment: yeah i access directly to application server

Comment: Can you check the deployed address in the application server console?

Comment: there is no issue with the address. what is the reason behind it only opening after i add the server address to trust zone..please tell

Answer (score -2):

On Browser invoke you can add the following code. So as any certificate pop ups will be accepted

```
 if (sBrowserName.equals("IE")) {
            File file = new File(sBrowserDriver);
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
            DesiredCapabilities capab = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
            capab.setCapability(
                    InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,
                    true);
            webdriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capab);
```

Comment: This is totally incorrect: http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com.es/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html

Comment: isnt introduce_flakiness_by_ignoring_security_domains capability is for ignoring protected mode setting? I have already set it.this only ignores protected mode exception